# Rails broken association with custom ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, activerecord, associations

When I execute relation with custom foreign keys, rails does not pass id to query, but pass [[nil, nil]]:

```
jruby-1.7.11 :081 > u.user_privileges
UserPrivilege Load (61.0ms)  
SELECT "A_USERPRIVILEGES".* FROM "A_USERPRIVILEGES"  
WHERE "A_USERPRIVILEGES"."ID_A_USERS" = :a1  [[nil, nil]]  =>
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

I have rails 4.1, jruby-1.7.11, oracle_enhanced adapter and oracle 11g db

Here is my code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'A_USERS'
  self.primary_key = 'ID'

  has_many :user_privileges, foreign_key: 'ID_A_USERS', 
    primary_key: 'ID' # when i remove primary key here then nothing changing
end

class UserPrivilege < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'A_USERPRIVILEGES'
  self.primary_key = 'ID'

  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'ID_A_USERS', 
    primary_key: 'ID' # when i remove primary key here then nothing changing

  alias_attribute :user_id, :id_a_users # does not work too
end
```

Tables information:

```
  A_USERS:
    ID  NUMBER(38,0)

  A_USERPRIVILEGES:
    ID     NUMBER(38,0)
    ID_A_USERS NUMBER(38,0)
```

**Update**

I just create test project with *mysql* database with exactly same code and schema as writen above, and it's working...

Problem with oracle still unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'A_USERS'
  self.primary_key = 'ID'

  has_many :user_privileges, class_name: 'UserPrivilege', foreign_key: 'ID_A_USERS'
end

class UserPrivilege < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'A_USERPRIVILEGES'
  self.primary_key = 'ID'

  belongs_to :user, class_name:'User', foreign_key: 'ID', primary_key: 'ID_A_USER'
end
```

`foreign_key` is the key in the other table and `primary_key` is the key the current table so this is saying look for `ID_A_USER` in `A_USERS.ID`

Also when doing custom tables like this I always like to tell it the Asssociation class might be redundant but seems useful to me.

Also please not this from [here](http://blog.rayapps.com/2008/05/13/activerecord-oracle-enhanced-adapter/):

> Added emulate_integers_by_column_name option
>   Set the option below and as a result number columns with ID at the end of column always will be emulated as Fixnum (useful if in legacy database column type is specified just as NUMBER without precision information which by default is mapped to BigDecimal Ruby type)

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedAdapter.emulate_integers_by_column_name = true
```

Comment: Problem still the same, nothing changed.